# Problem with javascript object iteration: prints only 2 rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having troubles with the loop iteration of a js object.

```
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "{{route('api.mostra_corsi')}}",
                            contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "html",
                            data: "",
                            headers: {
                                "Authorization": "Bearer {{session('access_token')}}"
                            },
                            success: function(result) {
        
                                $("div#spinner-border").slideToggle();

                                var corsiArrayAll = JSON.parse(result);
                                console.log(corsiArrayAll);

                                $('table#corsi-table').append(
                                    "<thead><tr>"+
                                    "<th scope='col'>Nome</th>"+
                                    "<th scope='col'>Nome Corso</th>"+
                                    "<th scope='col>Numero Persone</th>"+
                                    "<th scope='col'>Data inizio corso</th>"+
                                    "<th scope='col'>Data fine corso</th>"+
                                    "<th scope='col'>Orario inizio corso</th>"+
                                    "<th scope='col'>Orario fine corso</th></tr></thead>"
                                );
                

                                var index = -1;
                                console.log(corsiArrayAll);

                                for(let corso in corsiArrayAll){
                                    
                                    index++;
                                    $('table#corsi-table').append(
                                        "<tbody><tr>"+
                                        "<td>"+corsiArrayAll["utente"].name+"</td>"+
                                        "<td>"+corsiArrayAll["corsi"][index].nome+"</td>"+
                                        "<td>"+corsiArrayAll["corsi"][index].inizio+"</td>"+
                                        "<td>"+corsiArrayAll["corsi"][index].fine+"</td>"+
                                        "<td>"+corsiArrayAll["corsi"][index].orario_inizio+"</td>"+
                                        "<td>"+corsiArrayAll["corsi"][index].orario_fine+"</td>"+
                                        "</tr></tbody>"
                                    );
                                }
                                
                            },

                            error: function(err) {
                                alert("Impossibile mostrare i corsi");
                            }

                        })
```

When I execute `for(let corso in corsiArrayAll)` it prints only two rows, despite corsiArrayAll has 4 rows as you can see below:

```
Object
corsi: Array(4)
0: {idCorso: 1, tipo: 1, nome: 'campo s', membriMax: 45, orario_inizio: '08:30:00', …}
1: {idCorso: 2, tipo: 2, nome: 'pista verde', membriMax: 18, orario_inizio: '13:00:00', …}
2: {idCorso: 3, tipo: 3, nome: 'red', membriMax: 33, orario_inizio: '09:00:00', …}
3: {idCorso: 4, tipo: 2, nome: 'test table', membriMax: 23, orario_inizio: '12:00:00', …}
length: 4
```

What stops the for each iteration? What is the best way to iterate this object and print correctly?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you’re using array, use for…of and there is really no need to track an `index` and increment it.

Comment: Try a console log on the for loop to see if it actually sees the object or something else

Comment: You are itering over the object not the array, the array is at `corsiArrayAll.corsi`, also use `for...of` for arrays not `for...in`

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
for(let corso of corsiArrayAll["corsi"]){
  console.log(corso);
  $('table#corsi-table').append(
    "<tbody><tr>"+
    //"<td>"+corso["utenti"].name+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+corso.nome+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+corso.inizio+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+corso.fine+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+corso.orario_inizio+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+corso.orario_fine+"</td>"+
    "</tr></tbody>"
  );
}
```

Forgot to specify inside the `for..in` ["corsi"]